# Is there a way to use a variable to get a specified parameter?

Tags: linux, bash

```
function f(){ i=1; echo "${!i}" ; }
f a b
```

Output: `a`

```
function f(){ i=1; echo "${!((i+1))}" ; }
f a b
```

Output:`bash: ${!((i+1))}: bad substitution`, the output I want is `b`

What is the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement [codeforester's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42967427/45375):

If you only need to access *positional* parameters in your function, you can use *array syntax* to extract the parameter of interest; array slicing syntax *does* support arithmetic expressions:

```
> function f(){ i=1; echo "${@: i+1 : 1}" ; }; f a b
b
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Bash doesn't allow an expression in variable indirection.  How about incrementing the value of `i` before using it within brace expansion, like this:

```
function f() { i=2; echo "${!i}"; }
```

From Bash manual:

> ${!prefix*} ${!prefix@}
>
> Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

Comment: I don't think this is the right quote from the manual. These expand to arrays of the *variable names* that start with *`prefix`*. The correct quote is the fourth paragraph of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), where `${!prefix*}` and `${!prefix@}` are actually mentioned as exceptions to the rule.